# Unity type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine'

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have installed the new InputSystem package in my Unity project. I have set the input to "new inputsystem" in the Unity Player Settings.
I have quit and restarted both Unity and VS Code.

But when I try to use the system in VS Code, I immediately get this error:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;              // <-error
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls;     // <-error
```

> The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]

What can I do to make VS Code recognise the Unity InputSystem package?

Comment: Are you sure you want "InputSystem", or you want UnityEngine.Input?

Comment: Did this help? https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-find-unityengine-inputsystem.807645/#post-5401134

Comment: Yes, InputSystem (the new one). That thread helps, but the issue keeps reappearing. It's so annoying!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The issue is that the required .csproj files (VSCode needs them to understand the available libraries) for the new package were not auto-generated when you installed the new package (it didn't happen for me either, maybe it is intentionally manual).

Go to `Edit -> Preferences...` and then click on `External Tools`. You need to tick the box to `Generate .csproj files for:` `Registry packages` (and any other ones you might want) and then click on `Regenerate project files`.

[image: Screenshot from Unity's Preferences dialog]

That should generate whatever is needed for VSCode to recognize the new package - you shouldn't even need to restart it.

Comment: Work perfectly - thank you. I didn't even need to restart VS Code

Comment: @Flippi - It seems you are right, I also didn't need the restart. Updated the answer

Comment: works like a charm (had to add multiple other packages as well tho ... but in general, very helpful answer. Thank you)

Comment: This will only work if the dependencies are actually there to be resolved. If regenerating does nothing for you, make sure to install the Input System from the package manager first.

Comment: @Pfinnn The question explicitly mentions that the package is already installed.

Comment: Great answer, `Regenerate project files` still almost always fixes any namespace / code autocompletion errors I have.

Answer (score 21):

There's multiple reasons for this issue

I had an existing **Assembly Definition** that needed an **Assembly Definition Reference** to *Unity.InputSystem*

[image: Assembly Definition in Project view]

I added an **Assembly Definition Reference** to *Unity.InputSystem* in the *inspector* for "Scripts"

[image: Assembly Definition in inspector, with Unity.InputSystem referenced]

Rebuild had 0 errors.

Comment: If you have written tests before, you must do this step because writing and running tests require you to have an Assembly Definition Reference

Comment: I want to add for those with the same problem that some of the starting templates of Unity use Assembly Definition References. For example, the karting game starting template has an Assembly Definition Reference in Assets > Karting > Scripts > AI > Karting Game.AI. You have to add the Unity.InputSystem Definition to this in the list of references for it to work.

Comment: I had imported assets which had files *.RUNTIME that I needed to do this for!!!

Answer (score 14):

You need to install the package. Go to Windows / Package Manager. Search Input system and press install confirm to restart and replace the old input system.

Comment: I did that :) I mention that in my question :) But it did help to restart several times and set the player settings manually. Somehow the dialog that asks if you want to switch to the new system never shows up.

Comment: This helped me. I thought changing it in the Player Settings would be enough.

Answer (score 11):

If you get errors when Unity is trying to resolve the dependencies for the new Input System.Follow these steps and it should work:
Regenerating your project only works, if you have the Input System actually installed.

1. Install Input System (Windows > Package Manager)

[image]

2. Set your project to new Input System (Project Settings > Player > Input System)

[image]

3. Regenerate Project Files

Like other answers suggested, try regenerating your project files. This will only work, if the previous steps were succesful.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Select your Input Action Asset, and turn on Generate C# Class from the inspector window and click on apply to generate a C# script file.

Comment: After trying all the above. This is the part I was lacking - good tip. Weird it's not on by default?!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue (Mac 10.15.17 with Unity 2019.3.151f1 personal) but the above didn't work 100% for me. Here was my solution:

First, I ensured that I installed the InputSystem package via the package manager. Window > Package Manager. Search for it and you should be able to install 1.0.2 which is the newest as of this post.

From there, I ensured that VS code was setup correctly. I when to Unity > Preferences > External Editor and ensured that VS code was the correct editor. I then selected Regenerate project files.

Lastly, on the script I was using, I included it in the top of the file like so:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
```

Answer (score 0):

close the Unity and VB, remove these files from the project folder *.sln
*.csproj , run unity then click Assets -> open C# project

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
Go to `Edit -> Preferences...` and then click on `External Tools`. Remove the tick from the box for: `Registry packages` (and any other ones you might want) and then click on `Regenerate project files`. 
I don't know why but it worked for me (no need to restart VS Code) 
[Image of the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLPvu.png) 
**Environment:** 
Unity version: `2020.2.7f1` 
VS Code version: `1.61.2` 
Input System Package version: `1.2.4`

Comment: This actually worked for me! Although it doesn't make much sense it seems to fix some underlying bug.

Comment: @einUsername see?! that's why I mentioned "I don't know why but it worked" and yet I got negative vote :)

Answer (score 0):

I did all the above and still had the problem. What finally, helped me was:

Changing VS Code package to 1.2.3. You can do that by going to:

```
Packages/Manifest.json
```

finding:

> "com.unity.ide.vscode"

and changing version from "1.2.4" to "1.2.3"

The original solution was posted by user Cartina: https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-find-unityengine-inputsystem.807645/

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue, and solved it. so, leaving a note here.

#### my case

In my case, after installing the new InputSystem package by `Package Manger` on Unity Editor, and then restarting Unity Editor following the appeared dialog, I could see `Input System` under `Packages` folder on `Project` view. However, any reference to namespece `UnityEngine.InputSystem` got errors.

What I found that Unity.InputSystem.dll didn't exist under `[Project Dir]/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.InputSystem.dll`, which is what the Unity project refers to. This path can be found in `Assembly-CSharp.csproj`, placed right under Unity project directory.

Actually, it was not only for Input System package but also the same for all the other packages I uses. `[Project Dir]/Library/ScriptAssemblies` only had 2 files, `Assembly-CSharp.dll` and `Assembly-CSharp.pdb`, although this directory should hold dll files from all the installed packages.

#### solution

My solution was simple.

1. delete `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` file ( to be regenerated at some stage )
2. close Unity Editor
3. close Unity Hub
4. open Unity Hub
5. open Unity Editor

At the last step, before Unity Editor fully waked up, I could see all the package dll files are loaded to `[Project Dir]/Library/ScriptAssemblies` directory.

I'm not so sure whether csproj file delete and Unity Hub restart was necessary, but this is what I did, which recovered my broken project.

#### my environment

- Unity 2019.4.14f1
- macOS 10.15.7
- Visual Studio 8.8.4

Comment: deleting Assembly-CSharp.csproj is just enough.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (Windows, Unity 2019.4 15f1, Visual Studio Code 1.53.0, Input System 1.0.2)
Setting the Architecture of the project to x86_64 helped.

File-> Build Settings -> Plattform (PC, MAC & Linux Standalone)

I'm not sure though if this could even effect VS Code or if I did anything else in between to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna Using Something Like inputField Or Etc.
you can do it by add

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was creating my Script in a third-party folder (Mirror). As soon as I moved it to my Scripts folder it worked.