# Unity InputSystem wont work because namespace not found *i tried almost everything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

i tried everything from creating a new project, downloading inputsystem from packagemanager, manually and ... i tried editing assembley.csharp and adding hintpath... i tried reinstalling and importing old assets which input system worked well...

[{
"resource": "/C:/Driver/GAME MAKING/Repos/Unity2D/Pong-2-001018/Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs",
"owner": "csharp",
"code": "CS0234",
"severity": 8,
"message": "The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]",
"source": "csharp",
"startLineNumber": 6,
"startColumn": 19,
"endLineNumber": 6,
"endColumn": 30
}]

this is the problem. i just cant fix it it kills me. i can go back to old input system but why it shouldnt work?

even i downloaded last version of .net, runtime and sdk.

Comment: Did you try the solutions suggested in this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636944

Comment: no i tried all f them but i found another way but its not stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAl5QLZ69Pg&t=182s) but I have to do this everytime I build or play.

I just add this :

```
<Reference Include="Unity.InputSystem">
        <HintPath>C:\Driver\GAME MAKING\Repos\Unity2D\Pong-2-001018\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.InputSystem.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

to `assembly.csharp` and changed vscode version to 1.2.0

Also having generate `.charp` r json files ticked in edit>external editore made everything worse. If you dont need them uncheck all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).